# Holding locks on two objects

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, thread-synchronization

I have a question about locks and synchronization.

I have a method that locks object 1, and other method that locks object 2:

```
private void a(){
    synchronized(obj1){
        System.out.println("Object 1 being used");
    }
        System.out.println("Object 1 finished");

}

private void b(){
    synchronized(obj2){
        System.out.println("Object 2 being used");
    }
        System.out.println("Object 2 finished");

}
```

Also I have a third method:

```
private void c(){
for(int i=0;i<=0;i++){
        a();
        b();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

I want to hold the lock on both objects, 1 and 2 while the method `c` is running, after `c` is done, both locks can be released. How can I achieve this? I tried putting them into a `for` loop, but the methods `a` and `b` just start and finish.

Answer (score 1):

Have the c method acquire both locks in nested blocks:

```
synchronized (obj1) {
    synchronized (obj2) {
         // c method logic here
    }
}
```

Intrinsic locks are re-entrant so it doesn't matter that methods a and b already acquire them.

If you make more than one method that does this, make sure they acquire the locks in the same order, to avoid deadlocks.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)